# addendum to 3 blues before 4 reds probability question

Tags: probability

The [earlier answer to the following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821992/probability-of-blue-3-times-before-red-4-times) was checked ( by me ) and turned out to be incorrect ( atleast as far as I can tell because the denominator needs to include all the ways that any of the two events can happen ) so I wanted to start a new thread in order to explain my reasoning. Feel free to correct me if anything seems wrong with it. I repeat the question below.

Hi: interesting probability question here. you have a bag with a red ball and a blue ball in it. The rules of the game are

1) At each trial, a ball is taken out of the bag without looking by an unbiased person.

2) At each trial, after the ball is taken out of the bag, it is returned to the bag.

3) At each trial, the color of the chosen ball is noted.

The probability question is: What is the probability that a blue ball is picked 3 times BEFORE a red ball is picked 4 times.

I reason the following way: The probability of a blue ball being picked 3 times before a reds ball is picked 4 times is equal to the number of ways of 3 blues being picked before four rads are picked divided by the total number of ways of picking either 3 blues or 4 reds. Denote the numerator as N and the denom as D.

First I will calculate N: The number of ways of picking 3 balls before picking 4 reds is equal to the number of ways of picking 3 blue balls in 3 trials + the number of ways of picking 3 blue balls in 4 trials +  the number of ways of picking 3 blue balls in 5 trials + the number of ways of picking 3 blue balls in 6 trials.

Fix the last trial as a blue since the last trial has to be blue because the game ends at that point.  Then the number of ways to obtain 3 blues is equal to the number of ways to obtain 2 blues in 2 trials + the number of ways to obtain 2 blues in 3 trials + the number of ways to obtain 2 blues in 4 trials + the number of ways to obtain 2 blues in 5 trials. This is equal to

2 choose 2 + 3 choose 2 + 4 choose 2 + 5 choose 2  where 2 choose 2 denotes the number of ways that the event A can happen and 3 choose 2 denotes the number of ways that the event B can happen and 4 choose 2 denotes the number of ways that the the event C can happen and 5 choose 2 denotes the number of ways that the event D can happen.

Event A is just represented as blue blue ( 2 blues in 2 trials ) and then the last one has to be blue.
Event B  is represented by number of ways of picking 2 blues in 3 trials and then the last one is blue.
Even C is represented by the number of ways of picking 2 blues in 4 trials and then the last one is blue.
Event D is represented by the number of ways of picking 2 blues in 5 trials and then the last one is blue.

Note that A, B, C and D exclude the ways where 4 reds could have been picked.

Next I need to calculate D, namely the total number of ways of picking 3 blues or 4 reds.
So, we just have to figure out the cases where we can get 4 reds and then add these to
N in order to get the total number of ways that either event, 3 blues or 4 reds, could happen. Consider the number of trials from 3 to 6 and assume the last pick is a red so that we end the game on 4 reds.

3 trials : There is one way to get 3 reds in 3 trials ( R R R ) and then the last pick is a red. Denote this as event E and the number of ways is 3 choose 3.

4 trials : There are 4 choose 3 ways to get 3 reds in 4 trials and then the last pick is a red. Denote this as event F and the number of ways is 4 choose 3.

5 trials: There are 5 choose 3 ways to get 3 reds in 5 trials and then the last pick is a red. Denote this as event G and the number of ways is 5 choose 3.

So, N/D =   Number of ways in  A + Number of ways in  B + Number of ways in C + Number of ways in D/( Number of ways in A + Number of ways in B + Number of ways in C + Number of ways in  D + Number of ways in  E + Number of ways in F + Number of ways in G)

= 1 + 3 + 6 + 10/( 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 4 + 10 ) = 20/35 = 57.14 percent.

A friend of mine ran a simulation and concluded that the probability was 21/32 = 65.6 percent  so I am probably still doing something wrong somewhere but I don't see where. Thanks for any comments, corrections or suggestions.

Comment: I had answered the question earlier, and obtained in a simpler way an answer that is numerically the same as the $\frac{21}{32}$ discussed here.

Comment: Mark: it would have been helpful to have linked to the earlier answer

Comment: Also the answer of Vera ($P[X\geq 3]$ where $X$ has binomial distribution with $n=6$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$) on the question referred to is okay (nice and concise) and leads to $\frac{21}{32}$.

Comment: Mark: Your counting method fails because the events you are counting are not equally probable. If you take the probabilities into account you get Bananarama's earlier answer or David's answer here.  If you want to use counting equally probable events, then see Vera or André Nicolas's earlier answers on how to reframe the question.

Answer (score 1):

The experiment is "successful" if and only if the third blue ball appears on draw $3,4,5$ or $6$.

The probability that it is on draw $3$ is $\frac{1}{8}$.

It is on draw $4$ if the first three draws give two blues and a red, and the fourth draw is blue: probability $C(3,2)\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{2}$.

It is on draw $5$ if the first four draws give two blues and two reds, and the fifth draw is blue: probability $C(4,2)\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{2}$.

It is on draw $6$ if the first five draws give two blues and three reds, and the sixth draw is blue: probability $C(5,2)\frac{1}{32}\frac{1}{2}$.

Adding all these gives $\frac{21}{32}$.

Comment: my sincere apologies to vera, andre and bananarama who were all correct in their replies. that will teach me to disregard answers that seem too simple without reading them carefully (atleast in the case of vera and andre. I still have to go back and understand bananarama's approach ). thanks also goes to david and drhab for pointing out that the other answers were fine and for providing new approaches. all the best and my sincere apologies.

Comment: @markleeds math.se is all about learning - no need to apologise for that!!  Please continue to ask good and interesting questions!

Answer (score 1):

The probability can be written as: $$\binom{2}{2}2^{-3}+\binom{3}{2}2^{-4}+\binom{4}{2}2^{-5}+\binom{5}{2}2^{-6}$$
as done by [David](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/822494/75923) and [Bananarama](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/822031/75923). But also as: $$2^{-6}\left[\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{6}\right]$$
in the style of [Vera](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/822011/75923) and [André](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/822002/75923).

Looking at $X$ as a binomially distributed rv with parameters $n=6$
and $p=\frac{1}{2}$ the first expression can be recognized as: $$P\left(X\geq3\right)=\sum_{k=3}^{6}P\left(X\geq3\mid E_{k}\right)P\left(E_{k}\right)$$
where $E_k$ stands for the event that the third succes was achieved
at the $k$-th experiment .

The second can be recognized as: $$P\left(X\geq3\right)=\sum_{k=3}^{6}P\left(X=k\right)$$
If I would have to make a choice then I would go for the second.